# NoClassDefFoundError___The system can not find the specified path__No projects found to import

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I just wrote a simple applet using Eclipse Juno, previously I got *NoClassFoundError* running it through web browser and after closing Eclipse and reopen it I can't even run the applet. I tried to import the project. The error this time was *No project found to import*. I checked with command prompts for directories to see if I can at least get to the Java file and I got a *System can not find the specified path* error when I tried to move the directory to the package name. How do I fix this?

```
package Ch02Execises;
import java.awt.Graphics ;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
public class AppletDemo1 extends JApplet {
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Hello W3",20,30);
}
}
```

---

```
<html>
<p><h1>This is not displaying
</h1></p>
<applet CODE="AppletDemo1.class" WIDTH ="300" HEIGHT="150">
</applet> 
</html>
```

Comment: post your sample code with stack trace of the exception. Looks like a classpath issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to reimport the project? Did Eclipse crash and delete it from your workspace? Add code/errors/screenshots to your question for better responses.

Comment: at this point I can't find a way to run the application because I can't import it, and through the command prompt it is impossible to because the system can not find the path to the java file so that i compile and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recovering from local history.

If that does not work, check if there is a `.classpath` and `.project` file in the project directory. These are created by eclipse. If not present, create a new project by specifying the folder location again and try running it.

Also you can run the applet from commandline by using `appletviewer` in JAVA's bin directory.

Comment: Thank you I checked there was no [tag:.classpath] and [tag:.project] I deleted the package [ created a new [tag:project] within the same source file and it is working and can be displayed in web browser.